# Dimming Control by String and adding handler

Tags: vb.net, object, controls, addhandler

I want to add a handler to a control that i find by its name.
The Problem is that it is not possible to Dim an control from a Button or RadioButton or something like this...

```
Dim control As Control = FindName(MyObject.Name.ToString)
            AddHandler control.MouseEnter, Sub()
                                               Try
                                                   Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
                                                   Tooltip.SetToolTip(control, control.Name.ToString)
                                               Catch

                                               End Try

                                           End Sub
```

In the code i could dim control as Button but then e.g. RadioButtons would not work. And I do not want to have a code that always checks for the ObjectType and then go into an if part like

```
If TypeName(MyObject).ToString = "Button" then
...
else if TypeName(MyObject).ToString = "Label" then
...
else if TypeName(MyObject).ToString = "RadioButton" then
...
End If
```

Is there a better solution then doing it this way?

E.g. something like

```
Dim Control as TypeName(MyObject).ToString = FindName(MyObject.Name.ToString)
```

Comment: Think you need to expand a little bit as I'm trying to understand what `MyObject` is. Is it something you have declared or are you looping through controls?

Comment: I am looping through controls and get their children until no child is left - then go to the next one.. and for each child I want to try to add this Handler

Comment: Think then you just need to reference the control. MouseEnter is pretty standard for controls. In your loop `For Each ctr As Control` place the code `AddHandler ctr.MouseEnter`. Do the same for the child controls. It looks like you're already doing this or close to it. Might need to include more code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
For Each ctr As Control In Me.Controls
    AddHandler ctr.MouseEnter, Sub()
                                   Try
                                       Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
                                       Tooltip.SetToolTip(ctr, ctr.Name.ToString)
                                   Catch

                                   End Try
                               End Sub
Next
```

You would need to expand on this to each child if you're looping through parent objects like panels etc but the concept should work.

**EDIT**:

This should work for any control that has children:

Declare this at the top of your form/class:

```
Private _controls As New List(Of Control)
```

Use this to add the handler:

```
For Each ctr As Control In Me.Controls
    AddHandler ctr.MouseEnter, Sub()
                                   Try
                                       Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
                                       Tooltip.SetToolTip(ctr, ctr.Name.ToString)
                                   Catch

                                   End Try
                               End Sub
    If ctr.HasChildren Then
        _controls = New List(Of Control)
        GetChildren(ctr)
        For Each childCtr As Control In _controls
            AddHandler childCtr.MouseEnter, Sub()
                                                Try
                                                    Dim Tooltip As New ToolTip()
                                                    Tooltip.SetToolTip(childCtr, childCtr.Name.ToString)
                                                Catch

                                                End Try
                                            End Sub
        Next
    End If
Next
```

And something like this will populate the `_controls` list with the child controls:

```
Private Sub GetChildren(ByVal container As Control)

    For Each childCtr As Control In container.Controls
        _controls.Add(childCtr)
        If childCtr.HasChildren Then
            GetChildren(childCtr)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```